# how to move to next view controller after showing alertview

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have iPhone and I want that when `AlertView` is shown and user presses **OK** button after that view should be changed but it is not happening.

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
  return;
  [self moveToView];

-(void)moveToView
{
    MainViewController*targetController=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `UIAlertViewDelegate`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Code to move to next view
    [self moveToView];
}
```

**Note**: Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your interface Declaration. Also while declaring UIAlertView set the delegate to self.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Seems incorrect. Should be implementing the interface's [`didDismissWithButtonIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:) method rather than [`clickedButtonAtIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:).

Answer (score 6):

Its simple. Implement UIAlertViewDelegate and put code there.

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   MainViewController*targetController=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
   [targetController release];
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The dialog (UIAlertView) is gone when `didDismissWithButtonIndex` is invoked, so you can push views to the nav controller safely. The [incorrect accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11411381/642706)’s use of `clickedButtonAtIndex` to push views causes bad things to happen, ranging from nothing happening visually (older iOS) to exceptions that lead to a crash (iOS 7).

Answer (score 5):

in .h , implemented UIAlertViewDelegate

```
 @interface ClassName : ParentClassName <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

in .m , Add this method,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

      [self moveToView];

}
```

Comment: Nope, attempting to push views while the UIAlertView is still on screen (during `clickedButtonAtIndex`) is bad. Use `didDismissWithButtonIndex` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11411404/642706).

Answer (score 4):

Implement alert view's delegate:

In your yourClass.h file:

```
@interface yourClass : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{

}
@end
```

In your yourClass.m file:

```
@implementation yourClass

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self moveToView];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Well , you are setting self as the delegate of the UIAlertView. That is correct and it's the first step you must take. After that go ahead and implement this method :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self moveToView];
}
```

You can also make a switch statement here to see what button was pressed. But since you only have the OK button on the AlertView , it's not necessary.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Implement your code in  `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method and also add `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your class .h file.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        NSLog(@"The index: %d",buttonIndex);
        MainViewController*targetController=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
        [targetController release];
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.